# How to prepare UWP package not signed

Tags: uwp

I have to send to my customer a UWP package not signed, because he will sign it later with his Windows Store Certificate/Account.

I usually make unsigned apk (for Android) and xarchive (for iOS).
What is the right way with UWP?

Answer (score 1):

It's very similar to your other platforms. As long as your customer knows how to sign the Appx format for UWP, you can build your application and provide them with the built Appx for signing with their cert.

If they're not sure on how to sign it, you can provide them documentation on the SignTool included as part of the Windows SDK (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: And before that, you may follow [this document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/02/12/create-a-windows-store-appx-package-and-sign-it/) to create an unsigned package. I also answer the question at [MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cd9709d0-a63f-4d8c-9388-8ec60dd2a520/how-to-prepare-uwp-package-not-signed?forum=windowsstore).